# Accelerometer or g-sensor?

Tags: word-choice

Everything is in the title... I'm writing a technical report (Master of Engineering) and I wonder which term is the correct one : `accelerometer` or `g-sensor`

I've seen both in the litterature, but I thought maybe there is  a slight difference bewteen them.

I don't know if I should post this here or on a more oriented SO forum (Electricial Engineering), but I'm sure a Mod will move it if not.

Comment: Yeah, this is more industry-specific jargon than English usage.  I'd say use whatever seems more prevalent in the literature, or more specifically in the journal where you intend to submit (if applicable).

Comment: I've dealt with these devices off and on since 1970, and it's always been "accelerometer".  One might use "G-sensor" when describing the device in a non-technical sense, or if the particular corner of technology you're dealing with chooses to use that term, but not generally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, a *g-sensor* **is** an *[accelerometer](http://www.dimensionengineering.com/info/accelerometers)*.

You might see [some literature](http://acer--uk.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/29926/~/inaccurate-gyroscope-(g-sensor)-on-the-iconia-tab-b1-a71) inaccurately refer to a *g-sensor* as a *gyroscope*; but when you dig deeper, you see that they're actually referring to an accelerometer after all.

[This article](http://world.wikomobile.com/a1062-different-sensor-types) summarizes the different types of sensors you might find in a modern smartphone, and accurately distinguishes between a g-sensor and a gyroscope.

For a formal technical article, *accelerometer* would be a better word to use.

Comment: 'g' is the local acceleration due to gravity, which is a constant.

Comment: @Ami Tell that to Acer...